# Attempting to show a <div> element with the blur function

Tags: jquery, hide, show, blur

I am trying to get the `<div class="error">` element to show when i remove the cursor from the `input` text box, but it's not working with the jquery `blur` function. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    <h1>BMI Calculator</h1>
    <p>This is a BMI calculator.</p>
    <div class="error" style="width: 100px, height: 100px, background-color: blue"></div>
    <form action="calc.htm">
        Weight: <input type="number" name="weight_lb">lb<br/>
        <br/>
        Height: <input type="number" name="height_foot">feet
        <input type="number" name="height_in">in
        <br/></br>
        <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Calculate" name="calc">
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.error').hide();
            $('input[type="number"]').blur(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.error').show();  
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi i have check your code the script you have write is working your fault was in the style of the div of the error box you should use ";" not "," between the each style parameter 
you should correct this line

```
<div class="error" style="width: 100px, height: 100px, background-color: blue">
```

and replace it with :

```
<div class="error" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue">
```

check the snippet :

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.error').hide();
            $('input[type="number"]').blur(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.error').show();  
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>BMI Calculator</h1>
    <p>This is a BMI calculator.</p>
    <div class="error" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue"></div>
    <form action="calc.htm">
        Weight: <input type="number" name="weight_lb">lb<br/>
        <br/>
        Height: <input type="number" name="height_foot">feet
        <input type="number" name="height_in">in
        <br/></br>
        <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Calculate" name="calc">
    </form>
```